# Lubuntu 20.04 - Single-click to open/run don't work

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, mouse, gui, .desktop

I just installed Lubuntu 20.04 and setting the mouse to single click in the GUI don't work - After checking "*Single click to activate items*" box in "*Preferences / LXQt settings / Keyboard and Mouse*", I still have to double click to open files/apps on the desktop and folders. Is this the right spot to achieve what I'm looking for? Is there a fix for this? Maybe a command line or a better GUI? Any advice is appreciated. -Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Open any folder click on the hamburger
- Click on preferences
- Click on Behavior tab
- Click on Single click to open items